# How can I write a view callable that displays static html files in pyramid?

Tags: python, url, filesystems, pyramid

In my pyramid app, I have several static html files under tutorial/tutorial/pages/name.html (for example). How can I write a view callable for this? Would this work?

```
     @view_config(renderer='view_page')
     def view_page(request):
         return {} # no values have to be passed to the template
```

then in the **init**.py file

```
config.add_route('view_page', 'tutorial:pages/{name}.html')
```

What do I need to put in the def view_page(request) function to call that name.html file specifically and then display its content?

Comment: can you use a static view ?

Comment: yes I think so. But how would I call it in a view callable?

Comment: actually, doesn't look like you can with add_static_view ( http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.0-branch/narr/assets.html )

but directs you to this http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.0-branch/narr/assets.html#advanced-static

you can also look at the deform and debug-toolbar source code -- they do a lot of static routes and views to accomplish similar things to what you're doing.

Comment: @JonathanVanasco you're linking to 1.0 documentation.

Comment: i thought that was the latest link. sorry.  search engine results.  http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.4-branch/narr/assets.html  and http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.4-branch/narr/assets.html#advanced-static

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pyramid's `static_view` is a view capable of serving files from a directory. The part you really haven't explained is what the URLs are like for these static pages. For example, if they are all under a common prefix, you could use `static_view` (option 1). If they are not, then you have to create a view per page and serve it up directly (option 2).

### option 1

url:

```
/foo/bar.html
/foo/baz/boo.html
```

static view:

```
config.add_static_view('/foo', 'tutorial:pages')
```

tutorial/pages hierarchy:

```
tutorial/pages/bar.html
tutorial/pages/baz/boo.html
```

`add_static_view` is effectively like calling `add_route('foo', '/foo/*subpath')`, and it serves up the `subpath` relative to `tutorial:pages`.

### option 2

```
config.add_route('foo', '/foo')
config.add_route('bar', '/foo/bar')

@view_config(route_name='foo', renderer='tutorial:pages/foo.html.mako')
@view_config(route_name='bar', renderer='tutorial:pages/bar.html.mako')
def static_view(request):
    return {}
```

Notice the `.mako` suffix to invoke the mako renderer. There is no `.html` renderer by default, but you could make one.

Comment: option 1 seems to fit my needs. They should all be viewable under www.domain.com/pages/(name).html. In this case, what should I add in my view_page callable?

Comment: In option 1 I did not mention the need for a `view_page` callable. I'm confused.

Comment: Is there no need for a view_page callable? Perhaps you only need a view callable when you use config.add_route?

Comment: `config.add_static_view` behind the scenes adds its own route and view.

Comment: ok interesting. So is the name of the view just '/foo'? If I call a request like request.route_url('/foo'), would it know what I am talking about?

Comment: No. http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.4-branch/narr/assets.html#serving-static-assets

Comment: nvm I think that I should enter a request with request.static_url9